# Showing the scores and number of times each score was obtained

Tags: c, arrays, count

my name is Adriel, am new to the site and programming. Anyways I need some help and guidance with my assignment. I am to create a program in C that will allow the user to enter up to 5000 exam scores. Then give the user 5 options that are to get the average grade, show all exams from high to low, curve the exams up by 5 or down by 5 **AND** the one that I can't do is to display the scores and how many times they were obtained.

this is my code:

```
main() {

    //Declared variables
    char choice;
    int i, j, a, n;
    int examScore = 0, HIGH = 0, LOW = 0, AVG = 0, count = 0, sum = 0, scoreCount = 0;
    int highlow[5000], highExam, lowExam;

    do{//Begin do while #1
        CLS;
        FLUSH;
        printf("=========================\n");
        printf("===== Score program =====\n");
        printf("=========================\n");
        printf("A. Exam scores\n");
        printf("B. Exams average\n");
        printf("C. Exam score High - Low\n");
        printf("D. Times scores obtained\n");
        printf("E. Curved up 5 pts\n");
        printf("F. Curved down 5 pts\n");
        printf("Q. Exit program\n");
        printf("=========================\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        scanf(" %c", &choice);
        choice = toupper(choice);
        switch (choice){//Begin switch
        case 'A':
            CLS;
            printf("Please Enter The Number of exams:\n");
            scanf("%d", &n);

            printf("Please Enter %d Numbers\n", n);
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
                scanf("%d", &highlow[i]);
            }//end for loop
            highlow[examScore];
            count++;
            sum = sum + examScore;
            AVG = sum / count;
            highExam = examScore + 5;
            lowExam = examScore - 5;
            CLS;
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (j = i + 1; j<n; ++j)
                {
                    if (highlow[i]<highlow[j])
                    {
                        a = highlow[i];
                        highlow[i] = highlow[j];
                        highlow[j] = a;
                    }
                }
            }


            PAUSE;
            break;

        case 'B':
            CLS;
            printf("Exam average is: %i\n", AVG);
            PAUSE;
            break;

        case 'C':
            CLS;
            printf("The numbers arranged in descending order are given below\n");

            for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)

            {

                printf("%i\n", highlow[i]);
            }
            PAUSE;
            break;

        case 'D':
            CLS;
            printf("Amount of times scored was obtained: %i-%i\n", examScore, count);
            PAUSE;
            break;

        case 'E':
            CLS;
        //  printf("Exam scores curved up by 5 pts: %i\n", highExam);
            PAUSE;
            break;

        case 'F':
            CLS;
        //  printf("Exam scores curved down by 5 pts: %i\n", lowExam);
            PAUSE;
            break;

        case 'Q':
            CLS;
            printf("Quitting program. Goodbye.\n");
            PAUSE;
            break;

        default:
            printf("- Invalid entry -\n");
            PAUSE;
            break;

        }//End switch

    } while (choice != 'Q');//End do while #1


}//End main
```

As you may see am still far from done, but the other parts are not a big concern to me. Any help and advice would be very appreciate.

Comment: What specifically are you having a problem with?

Comment: C gives us freedom to create functions .Then why did you put code inside switch cases. Using function will make your program good to understand and reusable.

Comment: By curve up 5, do you mean that if your exam scores are: 4,9,2,6,3... then result is 9,14,7,11,8.......?

Comment: @aalganaraz I am also having same question as above.

Comment: am still figuring out how to use this site. But yeah each score need to go up by 5 and the other option is down by 5, those are to different cases.

Comment: Anyways that part is not of much concern. @dbush the part that am having problems with is case D displaying the scores and how many times each score was obtained.

Comment: He didn't specify about the range but I would guess that it is from 0 to 100. which is what I've being using

Answer (score 0):

Why is it so difficult to count the number of times each score is in your `highlow` array?

I was thinking of a different approach until I noticed that you had a sorted array of the scores, so any duplicate scores will be adjacent to each other.  It should be easy enough to look at the value of `highlow[0]` and then compare that to `highlow[1]` to see if `highlow[0]` is duplicated.  You just do that until you find that the next isn't a duplicate, then you start looking for duplicates of the next number.

Comment: I understand the logic behind what you are saying, but am not sure how to put it to practice. Would I need a new loop for that or just included in the one that sorts the numbers?

Comment: You have 2 loops that sort the numbers. I suppose that you could try to do it in the sort (by including a `==` case), but I suspect that it would be difficult to avoid counting values multiple times. This is a case of "get it working" before "make it optimal", particularly since your sort is bubble sort, which is far from optimal already.  It works, so leave it until you're done, then back up your code, and then if you want to experiment with better algorithms.

Comment: Am sorry to even ask this but could you give me an example of how to make it work, cuz I truly don't understand.